# How can I play sound in real time with django?

Tags: python, django

Suppose, that I've got frames that continously received one after another.

How can I play them, when user in on some particular page?

I know that I can probably write them in two wav files (like a buffer) and switch the buffer from one to another in loop, but that's seems silly.

Maybe I can somehow play the stream in browser?

I'm new to web development...

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a django problem? I think this has to do with plugins and the browser, not really django.

Comment: Well... All I know is basically the django. What tools do i need to use in your opinion?